# Executing PHP code stored in SQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've read a few posts about this that suggest using eval but then say how its dangerous (I don't know why) but I don't think it will work for my current need.

My issue is that I have a blog post db table which has a column that contains all the content of the post. In this content I want to include a poll that lets the user vote a or b. This requires a database call to get the current votes to display to the user after they have voted . I'm guessing javascript would be possible but then anyone could look at the source code and see the query I'm making to the database which is risky. I have the php code working fine I just need a way to process it after code has been obtained from the DB

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Except that you can't query a DB with javascript...

Comment: Are you saving the user's vote via an AJAX call? If so, just do the query for total votes in the same script and return the result.

Comment: A safer approach would be to use something like Wordpress shortcodes - insert a placeholder marker in the post text, then execute some code and replace the marker with the result before displaying it.

Comment: This sounds like a dozen flavours of **wrong**. Are you really sure this is a good idea? I think if you better define your use cases you can avoid all of this.